# What do the Dutch academic titles "prof.dr.dr.h.c.ir." mean?

Tags: professorship, titles

Some Dutch academics - I think probably full professors with chairs - have a rather confusing string of abbreviated titles.

One example is [prof.dr.dr.h.c.ir. M.J. Plasmeijer](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~rinus/), but many other examples can be found by searching for that string.

What do these titles actually mean, individually and collectively?

Comment: It means they work in a country with a long aristocratic history and that they have a high opinion of themselves.

Comment: @Jigg True about the tradition, less so about the high opinion. It is listed as "Formally:" on that guy's site, and not with the primary display of the name. I think it's preferable to list your full title somewhere on your site (some people may need it for formal documents), even if you hardly ever use it yourself.

Comment: Academic titles become part of a person's legal name (so would have to be stated on certain documentation) in some countries (Austria is one, I believe); to see the full title is certainly not necessarily evidence that the person is boasting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here you go:

- *prof* is short for professor.
- *dr* is short for doctor, which signifies either MD or PhD.
- *dr. h. c.* stands for *doctoratus honoris causa*, which is an honorary title.
- *ir* stands for engineer (*ingenieur*).

In this case it means a professor (with a PhD) with an engineering background, who got an honorary title at some point.

Comment: I would add that *drs.* should **not** be confused with *dr.* This title, the [*Doctorandus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctorandus), simply means that the holder is entitled to begin PhD research.

Comment: Indeed. As a Dutch-English translator myself, I always recommend following JurLex in this matter when faced with translating one of these strings: drop all but the most important one. E.g.: prof. dr. ir. ABC = Prof. ABC / prof. dr. ABC = Prof. ABC / prof. drs. ABC = Prof. ABC / prof. mr. ABC = Prof. ABC, etc.