# What is the proper way for an abbreviation of assistant professor?

Tags: titles, assistant-professor

I am looking for the formally correct abbreviation of assistant professor. How do I refer to someone in that position in a letter or on a webpage? Is Asst. Prof. Dr. the right title?

Comment: Whatever you do, avoid *Ass Prof.*. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, what comes before professor (e.g. assistant, associate, full) is only really used in formal contexts, and in most other cases simply "Professor"/"Prof." is enough.

And, at least in the sciences, "Doctor"/"Dr." is typically used when that is the highest title.

I've never seen both "Professor" and "Doctor" used together.

So, in your case, I suppose "Prof. X" is good enough.

Comment: There are regional variations here. In Germany it is perfectly normal to write Prof. Dr. Smith, or Prof Dr. med. Dr. Smith (if (s)he has medical doctoral degree and one regular PhD), or Prof Dr. Drs. H.c. Smith (if (s)he has one regular PhD and multiple honorary doctoral degrees), etc.

Comment: For now I ended up using Dr. as that is the highest title he has which converts to our german standard. To my knowledge we do not have any title that compares to assistant professor.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Well in Germany the "Doctor" title becomes an official part of your name, right?  You can get your passport changed to incorporate it.  Such is what I've been told by a German colleague, anyway.  Incidentally, I see [this Q&A](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24536/what-do-the-dutch-academic-titles-prof-dr-dr-h-c-ir-mean) on the related sidebar about the dutch doing much the same thing as you mention for people with many titles.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy there is a subtle difference between the two cultures (I am Dutch and live in Germany). To exagerate: the Dutch do it but laugh about it, in Germany they do it and take it seriously. In the Netherlands, the doctor title cannot be added to your passport, as is the case in Germany.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy In Germany the doctor title can be added to your passport, but is not part of your name but a *namenszusatz*. But there are enough people in Germany who believe it.

Comment: In the UK, you'd usually only address a full professor as Prof - anybody else is likely to be Dr (assuming they have a PhD). Few non-Germans are likely to get upset about if, though. If in doubt perhaps use Prof.